# Handle duplicate record while importing and inserting csv file data into salesforce via vf page

Tags: apex

I have a weired requirement now. In the below pic column A, B, C needs to go to object Account and column D should go to another object Type__c and Type__c should be a child of Account.

Requirement is

Current code is working

If Id's are same then only one record is getting created in Account object and AccountNumber is getting inserted as CC978213;CD355119-A.

Where i am stuck is

When Id's are same one record is getting created in Account simulataneoulsy 1 record should get created in Type__c object if Type is having same value for that ID.And if column A, B , C are same but D is different, one record should get created for Account having one account number and 2 record should get crated in Type__c object .

[image]

```
public class importDataFromCSVController {
public Blob csvFileBody{get;set;}
public string csvAsString{get;set;}
public String[] csvFileLines{get;set;}
public List<account> acclist{get;set;}
    public map<string, string> csvmap = new map<string, string>();
  public importDataFromCSVController(){
    csvFileLines = new String[]{};
    acclist = New List<Account>(); 
  }

  public void importCSVFile(){
       try{
           csvAsString = csvFileBody.toString();
           csvFileLines = csvAsString.split('\n'); 


      for(Integer i=1;i<csvFileLines.size();i++){

           string[] csvRecordData = csvFileLines[i].split(',');
                if(csvmap.containsKey(csvRecordData[0])){
           csvmap.put(csvRecordData[0],csvmap.get(csvRecordData[0])+','+csvRecordData[3]);
               }
                else{
                csvmap.put(csvRecordData[0],csvRecordData[3]) ;
                    }
            }

           system.debug('@@@@@@'+ csvmap);
    for(string str : csvmap.keyset())
     {
       Account accObj = new Account() ;

           accObj.name = str ;             
           accObj.accountnumber = csvmap.get(str);                                                                      
           acclist.add(accObj); 

      }   

        insert acclist;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ApexPages.Message errorMessage = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'An error has occured while importin data Please make sure input csv file is correct');
            ApexPages.addMessage(errorMessage);
        }  
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you deciding that record is duplicated?

Comment: Currently for ex you can take id or name as duplicate record...Just for example ...i can modify it later..

Comment: Why you removed your code sample?

Comment: I am going to update the updated one..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this using map

Create a map and fill it and remove duplicate

```
map<string, string> csvmap = new map<string, string>();
for(Integer i=1;i<csvFileLines.size();i++){

           string[] csvRecordData = csvFileLines[i].split(',');
           if(csvmap.containsKey(csvRecordData[0]))
           svmap.put(csvRecordData[0],csvmap.get(csvRecordData[0])+','+csvRecordData[1])
           else
                svmap.put(csvRecordData[0],csvRecordData[1])                                                                       
   }
```

then iterate over this map

```
for(string str : svmap.keyset())
     {
       Account accObj = new Account() ;

           accObj.name = str ;             
           accObj.accountnumber = svmap.get(str);                                                                       
           acclist.add(accObj); 

      } 
      insert acclist;
```

**PS:** few things this is a case sensitive match if you want a case insensitive match then you can convert them into lower case

Comment: One small question.. Where we are inserting the account number with comma separated.. like test__c = CC978213, CD355119-A...

Comment: @learnjqueery  `svmap.get(str)` in this map value part we are storing account number in comma separated format. Then we will fill this in account number field.

Comment: if i want to insert accountnumber do i need to write as -   for(string str : csvmap.keyset())
     {
       Account accObj = new Account() ;

           accObj.name = str ;             
           accObj.accountnumber = str;
           accObj.test__c  =  csvmap.get(str);                                                                       
           acclist.add(accObj); 

      }

Comment: You should probably use `String.join` and a `Map<Id, Set<String>>` instead.

Comment: @learnjqueery if you want to insert account number in Test__c field then yes your format is correct.

Comment: Hey tushaar.. Can u help me for this weired requirement

Comment: @learnjqueery instead of editing your old question with new question you will get better response if you post this as new question and complete the old question. btw do you want to link account and Type records with each other?

Comment: sure i will post in new question

Comment: Hi Tushar i have posted as a new question

Comment: Yes tushar i need to link account and type